# xPath - Can you remove commas from node?

Tags: php, xpath

I have an xPath query that grabs plaintext from a div like this

```
xpath->query("//div[@id='main']//span[@class='meta']/text()")
```

This query returns `The text that I want,`

Is there anyway that I can remove that comma within my query?

Thanks

**EDIT:**

Using Mad's code from below, my query now looks like this (I've replaced the `,` in the example with the word `hello` to make it a bit less confusing.)

```
$search_term = $xpath->query("translate('//div[@id='main']//span[@class='meta']/text()', 'hello', '')");
```

And I'm attempting to echo the query results like this:

```
foreach ($search_term as $st) { 
echo $st->nodeValue; }
```

The error I'm receiving is

```
Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in ... on line 50
```

Comment: Is this Xpath 1 or 2? In XPath 2 there is the `replace()` function which does regex replace.

Comment: You can try it and if you get a big red error message, you've got XPath 1 :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**You could use [`translate()`](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/#function-translate) to replace the `,` character with empty an string:**

```
xpath->query("translate(//div[@id='main']//span[@class='meta']/text(), ',', '')")
```

Although, it could result in a trailing space if the comma was preceded or followed by a space in the `text()` node.

**You could then use [`normalize-space()`](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/#function-normalize-space) to remove leading/trailing whitespace:**

```
xpath->query("normalize-space(translate(//div[@id='main']//span[@class='meta']/text(), ',', ''))")
```

Although, it will also normalize sequences of whitespace in the middle of the text into single spaces.

**You could also use [`substring-before()`](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/#function-substring-before) to select the text preceding `,`:**

```
xpath->query("substring-before(//div[@id='main']//span[@class='meta']/text(), ' ,')")
```

However, if the string does not contain `,` then `substring-before()` will not return anything.

Comment: Awesome, I'll give this a shot. The trailing space shouldn't be an issue in this case, but it's nice to know how to remove it. Thanks Mads!

Comment: Mads, I'm using your code, and I believe it's working as the query itself isn't throwing any errors. However, when I attempt to echo my query results (with translate() now applied), I'm getting this error - "Invalid argument supplied for foreach()". I've updated my original post to show how I'm echoing out the query.

Comment: The `translate()` and `normalize-space()` functions expect a single string as input. In XPath 1.0 if you feed it a sequence of nodes it will select the first one and then return a string. Your code is expecting the sequence of nodes selected from your XPath. In XPath 2.0 you could do something like this `//div[@id='main']//span[@class='meta']/text()/normalize-space()`. With your current situation, it's probably easiest to select the node-set and modify the value inside of your for-each instead of 100% XPath, unless you can use XPath 2.0.

Comment: I'm pretty sure I'm on XPath 1, so I'm just going to stick with the rtrim method that Jon posted above. Marking your answer because it's an XPath solution though. Thanks again

Answer (score 2):

Looks like [`rtrim`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.rtrim.php) is the better choice if you want to remove a trailing comma. I don't see why involving the XPath with this would be preferable, but you could also do it with the [`fn:replace`](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-functions/#func-replace) function (XPath 2.0).

Comment: Jon, I was thinking it would be cleaner to handle it all in one xp query, if possible. Thank you for the links. I'm not sure how to find which version of xPath I'm using, so I'll probably just use rtrim. EDIT - rtrim did the trick.